# Manga where a girl's “dream world” turns out to be real

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main storyline is, every time the girl (mc) goes to sleep, she ends up in another world. This world seems to be set in olden times, and at first she thinks it's just a dream, but certain events lead to her realising it's real and that she actually went to another world. (I think what made her realise was when she saw someone she knew from her world, but I can't remember if that actually happened.)

The manga is pretty old, so I doubt this is helpful, so if you anyone knows anything similar, please let me know because it might be that one.

Comment: How old is "pretty old?"  When did you watch this?

Comment: This is a common premise. See [Dream Land](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DreamLand) and [Magical Land](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicalLand). (warning: TV Tropes links!) Check the Anime and Manga sections.

Answer (score 4):

["*The Vision of Escaflowne*"](https://myanimelist.net/anime/182/Tenkuu_no_Escaflowne) (*Tenkuu no Escaflowne*) maybe? If it had giant armour mecha.

> Hitomi Kanzaki is just an ordinary 15-year-old schoolgirl with an interest in tarot cards and fortune telling, but one night, a boy named Van Fanel suddenly appears from the sky along with a vicious dragon. Thanks to a premonition from Hitomi, Van successfully kills the dragon, but a pillar of light appears and envelopes them both. As a result, Hitomi finds herself transported to the world of Gaea, a mysterious land where the Earth hangs in the sky.
>
> In this new land, Hitomi soon discovers that Van is a prince of the Kingdom of Fanelia, which soon falls under attack by the evil empire of Zaibach. In an attempt to fight them off, Van boards his family's ancient guymelef Escaflowne—a mechanized battle suit—but fails to defeat them, and Fanelia ends up destroyed. Now on the run, Hitomi and Van encounter a handsome Asturian knight named Allen Schezar, whom Hitomi is shocked to find looks exactly like her crush from Earth. With some new allies on their side, Van and Hitomi fight back against the forces of Zaibach as the empire strives to revive an ancient power.

[image: The Vision of Escaflowne character image]

Comment: Oh, I've watched that before and it's not that - the manga hasn't been adapted into an anime

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of [*Dream Saga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Saga) (1997)?

From Wikipedia:

> It is a fantasy adventure tale about a young girl called Yuuki Wakasa, who one day acquires a magical red stone. The stone allows her to travel to Takamagahara (高天原 "High Plane of Heaven"), the dream world, when she sleeps, and can only return to Nakatsukuni (中ツ国 "middle country"), the real world, when she goes to sleep in the dream.
>
> Yuuki discovers that she must save the sun, Amaterasu, from being trapped and destroyed in Takamagahara, or the light will be lost from both worlds forever.

Comment: Hi there. I edited in the Wikipedia summary, but it'd be better if you could [edit] your post with panels or your own summary to explain how it's a match :)