# Manga about a girl who fights in dreams?

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I have this manga I read once a long time ago. It seemed to be about a girl and her friends who had different lives in their dreams, and fought evil or something in them, I think. They had magic powers, there were both boys and girls, and it might have been a *shoujo* manga.

It seemed early 2000's ish, and I think they were elementary schoolers.

Comment: Hithere! Could you maybe take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? What's a Dre, by the way? Also, I notice you tagged this with [fighting-fantasy]; those are [gamebooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_Fantasy) which, as far as I know, don't have anything to do with manga. Am I mistaken in that regard or did you mean there was fighting in a fantasy setting?

Comment: A similar question was https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192540/manga-where-a-girls-dream-world-turns-out-to-be-real where *The Vision of Escaflowne* was suggested, but the answer was deemed wrong, and it doesn't involve elementary schoolers.

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm new to this site but yes. It was fighting in a fantasy style. It automatically added that as I'm on mobile. I'll edit it :)

Comment: A very very long shot, https://myanimelist.net/anime/11285/Black%E2%98%85Rock_Shooter_TV?

Comment: I'm really not sure but it may be [Noragami](https://anilist.co/manga/54692/Noragami/). If so, tell me and I'll write a proper answer.